# document.title and docuemnt.write both are not working simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to open a new window on click of a button. It is opened successfully but I can't write data and set title simultaneously.

Does anybody have any idea?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title And Data Both</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("button").click(function(){
            var filename ="console.log";
           var newwin = window.open("","","width=200,height=100");


            newwin.document.title="Title";            
            newwin.document.write("<h1>XXXX</h1>");
       });
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button">Get Substring</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using which browser?

Comment: `document.write()` overwrites the contents of the window.  Set the title *after* (or use proper HTML and put a title tag in the head).

Comment: I am using Chrome browser.

Comment: `document.title` changes the `<title>` element. `document.write` erases everything (including the title tag.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `document.write()` overwrites **all** existing HTML(**including the title**).
One way you could do it, is to set the title after the write.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title And Data Both</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                var filename = "console.log";
                var newwin = window.open("", "", "width=200,height=100");

                newwin.document.write("<h1>XXXX</h1>");
                newwin.document.title = "Title";
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button">Get Substring</button>
</body>

</html>
```